# Will Handler callbacks be removed when onDestroy() is bypassed?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

I had a peculiar behaviour in my app where the Handler keeps on running even when the app is closed/killed. I used something like the following:

```
fun xyz() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        // do stuff
        xyz()
    }, 3000)
}
```

From the internet, I learned that having a single Handler is better (instead of creating a new handler every time) and you've to call `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to cleanup all the recursive callbacks. I'm using the following code to cleanup my handler after an activity is destroyed.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
}
```

In Android's [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()), it says that:

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

If the system kills my activity's hosting process without calling `onDestroy()`, will the handler and its callbacks be destroyed as well or will it keep running in the background?

Comment: Nope. If your process is killed, everything in it goes away, including your `Handler`. The behavior you describe often happens when you inadvertently create new `Handler` instances without cleaning up the old ones; e.g., if you have something like `hander = new Handler();` in `onResume()`, which can run multiple times between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `postDelayed` it will be put `Runnable` to `MessageQueue` of `MainThread`. As the document said `kill the activity's hosting process`, `process` kill it means all threads inside will be killed so your `Handler` kill too without `onDestroy` of `Activity` called